# How can I do a custom sort on the following html table, forcing some rows to always appear beneath others?

Tags: html, angularjs, sorting

I have the following data for a list of tasks:

[image]

I have an `HTML` table displaying this data, currently sorted by task name (todotask), `ascending`:

[image]

and task name (todotask), `descending`:

[image]

`Child Tasks` are those marked in italics namely `'A task to derive from'` (three times a child) and `'Collect a set of trains'` (once a child).  The `parent task` has the same name as the `child` and the following three facts are true:

1 - The `salmserna` ends in `33` (for both child and parent).

2 - Only a child has a `todosernm` and that equals the parent's `todosern`.

3 - The parent task is always created before the child.

HTML:

```
<th ng-click="sortTasks(tasks, 'todotask', $event)">Task <img id='sortedIcon' src='/static/tasksApp/img/sorting.png' class='pull-right sortingIcon'></th>
<th ng-click="sortTasks(tasks, 'todostart', $event)">Start</th>
<th ng-click="sortTasks(tasks, 'todoend', $event)">End</th>
```

Angular Controller:

```
$scope.sortTasks = function (sortable, colName, event) {

    // Sorting
    sortable.sort($scope.sort_by(colName, $scope.sortOrder, function (a) {
        if(a != null){
          return a.toUpperCase();
        }else{
          return null;
        }
    }));

    // Sorted icon
    $('#sortedIcon').remove();
    if ($scope.sortOrder) {
        $(event.currentTarget).append("<img id='sortedIcon' src='/static/tasksApp/img/sortingUp.png' class='pull-right sortingIcon'>");
    } else {
        $(event.currentTarget).append("<img id='sortedIcon' src='/static/tasksApp/img/sorting.png' class='pull-right sortingIcon'>");
    }

    // Switch next sorting order
    $scope.sortOrder = !$scope.sortOrder;
};
```

The above calls on the method `sort_by`, shown below:

```
/**
 * Sorter function
 * Can sort both alphabetically and numerically.
 */
 $scope.sort_by = function (field, rev, primer) {
     return function (a, b) {

       var nameA = primer(a['todotask']);
       var nameB = primer(b['todotask']);
       var startA = primer(a['todostart']);
       var startB = primer(b['todostart']);
       var endA = primer(a['todoend']);
       var endB = primer(b['todoend']);

       if(nameA == nameB){
         return (startA < startB) ? 1 : ((startA > startB) ? -1 : 0);
       }else{
         a = primer(a[field]);
         b = primer(b[field]);
         return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0)) * (rev ? -1 : 1);
       }
     };
 };`
```

I need the child tasks to ALWAYS appear beneath the parent, and for sorting by name, this works with the above code, so when the names are equal, it sorts by start date and ignores the direction (`rev`), keeping the children below the parents and making use of fact 3 above.

**THE PROBLEM:**

I'm really struggling to understand how I can edit the code to ensure the children are kept beneath the parents **WHEN SORTING BY START OR END**, either ascending or descending.

Currently things look like this when sorting by `start`, ascending:

[image]

and descending:

[image]

This is unsurprisingly sorting by start date!  I just can't get my head around how to keep the children beneath the parents when sorting by date.

In the `sortTasks` method, `sortable` is the array of tasks and each task has the properties available, such as:

```
task.todostart, task.todoend etc.....
```

I suppose fact 2 above should be considered in the sorting method somehow but any help would be great as I'm well and truly stuck.